How can I use mask-position to move the cutout to the right?
I'm currently trying to create a dynamic slider in PHP/CSS. My goal is to let the user upload any svg and use it as a shape to cut a piece of a background.
Everything is working as I'd like it to but somehow the shape does not align itself to the right. I know that the mask is covering the whole image so mask-position: top right; won't work here but I don't know any other option to control the mask position. I thought about maybe adding another div around it and cut out the mask again but I'd lose the gradiant if I try that. Does someone have an idea on how to set this up properly?


#homeSlider {
  font-family: 'Roboto';    
}

.slider-element {
  position: relative;
}

.slider-element .slider-mask {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mask-composite: exclude;
  mask-position: right top;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slider-element img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slider-element .slider-element-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 300;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 10%;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.slider-element .slider-element-content .teaser {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.slider-element .slider-element-content h1 {
  color: white;
}
.slider-element .slider-element-content .slider-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #AF9D6A;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  transition: all 200ms linear 0s;
}
.slider-element .slider-element-content .slider-button:hover {
  color: #AF9D6A;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
<div id="homeSlider">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slider-element">
      <div class="slider-mask" style="background: linear-gradient(45deg, #171E39B3 0%, #3E6792B3 100%); ; mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; viewBow=&quot;0 0 250px 270px&quot;><g><path d=&quot;M568,88.52C515.68,33.97,442.06,0,360.5,0,201.72,0,73,128.72,73,287.5c0,16.17,1.36,32.01,3.92,47.45C31.09,359.98,0,408.61,0,464.5c0,81.46,66.04,147.5,147.5,147.5,46.14,0,87.33-21.19,114.37-54.37,30.76,11.23,63.98,17.37,98.63,17.37,81.56,0,155.18-33.97,207.5-88.52V88.52Z&quot; fill=&quot;black&quot; /></g></svg>'), linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);"></div>
      <div class="slider-element-content">
        <div class="slider-teaser">
          Lorem Ipsum                           
        </div>
        <div class="slider-title">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="slider-button">
         read more                          
        </a>
      </div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/846">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




The problem is caused by your SVG in mask-image has incorrect viewBox and doesn't have width and height property defined.
Old (also the typo viewBow):
<svg viewBow="0 0 250px 270px">...

New:
<svg viewBox="0 0 569 612" width="569" height="612">...

Here's a corrected one that should work as expected:


#homeSlider {
  font-family: 'Roboto';    
}

.slider-element {
  position: relative;
}

.slider-element .slider-mask {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mask-composite: exclude;
  mask-position: right top;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slider-element img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slider-element .slider-element-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 300;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 10%;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.slider-element .slider-element-content .teaser {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.slider-element .slider-element-content h1 {
  color: white;
}
.slider-element .slider-element-content .slider-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #AF9D6A;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  transition: all 200ms linear 0s;
}
.slider-element .slider-element-content .slider-button:hover {
  color: #AF9D6A;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
<div id="homeSlider">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slider-element">
      <div class="slider-mask" style="background: linear-gradient(45deg, #171E39B3 0%, #3E6792B3 100%); ; mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; viewBox=&quot;0 0 569 612&quot; width=&quot;569&quot; height=&quot;612&quot;><g><path d=&quot;M568,88.52C515.68,33.97,442.06,0,360.5,0,201.72,0,73,128.72,73,287.5c0,16.17,1.36,32.01,3.92,47.45C31.09,359.98,0,408.61,0,464.5c0,81.46,66.04,147.5,147.5,147.5,46.14,0,87.33-21.19,114.37-54.37,30.76,11.23,63.98,17.37,98.63,17.37,81.56,0,155.18-33.97,207.5-88.52V88.52Z&quot; fill=&quot;black&quot; /></g></svg>'), linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);"></div>
      <div class="slider-element-content">
        <div class="slider-teaser">
          Lorem Ipsum                           
        </div>
        <div class="slider-title">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="slider-button">
         read more                          
        </a>
      </div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/846">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Be careful: viewBox is unitless. If you add e.g px it will invalidate this attribute (and fall back to 300x150). In your case it works as you also added width and height.

@herrstrietzel thanks for the correction! It sure is an oversight, let me fix it

@Moument:  AngYC's example illustrates a common problem: the uploaded SVG may contain severe syntax errors or - quite common - a non-ideal viewBox. So you should consider to add some sanitizing: e.g stripping unnecessary tags like scripts and do an auto-viewBox adjustment via getBBox()
